# (Purchased) terminology on Net Preferred Equity Issued

Tags: equities

I understand what we mean when we say: **Net Preferred Equity Issued** it is the total amount of Preffered Stocks plus their price. But does the chart mean when it says **(Purchased)**?

What other can it be?

(Please correct me in anything i got wrong...)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (Purchased) means is that the company can also buy back preferred stock and thus create the negative "Net Preferred Equity Issued" that you see around 2010. So the purchased is talking about the company purchasing preferred stock rather than issuing preferred stock.

Comment: so around 2010 it's around ~ -3Billion because it is in relation to the point where the line of the graph starts (Q42009) where it is zero. Right?

Comment: That is a little less clear. The graph says TTM which means trailing twelve months. So from Jan 1 2010 it would actually be the net preferred equity issued over the last twelve months not the beginning of the graph.